# Android - Saving in Shared preferences stopped working

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In my app I was using for more than 1 year "Shared preferences" to store some boolean values (if the user has seen the intro page for example). Now I added one more setting (if the user has seen the help page!) and all the settings stopped working...

I tried changing "commit" to "apply" with no luck. How could by just adding one more shared preference to make it stop working? Is there any properties limit?

My code:

```
public SharedPreferences getSettings() {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(AppConstants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
    return settings;
}
```

old Activity for Intro:

```
private void saveUserHasSeenIntro() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSettings().edit();
    editor.putBoolean(AppConstants.SETTING_BOOLEAN_HAS_SHOWN_INTRO_STEPS, true);
    editor.commit();
}
```

where intro boolean is being read:

```
Boolean hasShownIntroSteps = getSettings().getBoolean(AppConstants.SETTING_BOOLEAN_HAS_SHOWN_INTRO_STEPS, false);
if ( !hasShownIntroSteps ) {
    // show intro
} else {
```

New activity for help:

```
private void saveUserHasSeenHelp() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSettings().edit();
    editor.putBoolean(AppConstants.SETTING_BOOLEAN_HAS_SHOWN_HELP_STEPS, true);
    editor.commit();
}
```

where the "help" boolean is read:

```
Boolean hasSeenHelp = getSettings().getBoolean(AppConstants.SETTING_BOOLEAN_HAS_SHOWN_HELP_STEPS, false);
if ( !hasSeenHelp ) {
    // show help activity
} else {
```

Comment: accidentally did you delete any line while editing now? :)

Comment: @BobMalooga - that part is pseudo-code. The problem is that get "getBoolean" always returns "FALSE" while I have saved "true" before

Answer (score 0):

It can be a Memory Limitation on your `SharedPreferences` file and usually this comes with an `OutOfMemoryException`. I guess if something like that would happen you would probably seen it in your code, unless you are not reading/writing in another `Thread`. How big is your SharedPreferences file in numbers of key - value pair ?

Answer (score 0):

Your methods are fine and they should work perfectly. Check a couple of things just in case:

1. Ensure you don't call [clear()](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#clear()) or [remove()](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#remove(java.lang.String)) method of the `SharedPreferences` editor after saving your prefs by mistake.
2. Ensure the constants `AppConstants.SETTING_BOOLEAN_HAS_SHOWN_HELP_STEPS` and `AppConstants.SETTING_BOOLEAN_HAS_SHOWN_INTRO_STEPS` have different values as the former could overlap the second by mistake.
3. Just add a breakpoint after setting the new pref and read the value to check if it's set just after it.

   ```
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSettings().edit();
   editor.putBoolean(AppConstants.SETTING_BOOLEAN_HAS_SHOWN_HELP_STEPS, true);
   editor.commit();
   Boolean hasSeenHelp = getSettings().getBoolean(AppConstants.SETTING_BOOLEAN_HAS_SHOWN_HELP_STEPS, false);
   ```
4. In some extreme cases you could even implement [SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html) to see where your SharedPreferences are being changed to avoid unwanted pref sets.

Comment: 1) I use it only if the user logs out, but not anywhere else.
2) Yes they have different values
3)I did that. When you start the app, the "help" is false, after you see it it gets "true", then the intro is "false", after you see it, it is "true", when you move to the next acitivity I check both, strangely, the "help" is "false" and the "intro" is true (while both should be true). When you restart the app, both are "false"